# Are the leftovers from making stock good for anything?

Tags: stock, culinary-uses

Having made stock and strained it, can the meat and vegetables boiled up in the stock be used for anything, or should they go in the bin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The veggies aren't very palatable after such a long simmering (unless you like celery paste, I guess), but if you've thrown a whole chicken in the resulting meat is wonderfully tender and flavorful.

Comment: This is exactly what we do, and it works great. The chicken bits are good for things like risotto, and more.

Comment: If you have done the stock right, the meat will be fall of the bones flaky and kind of dry tasting, and very flavorless, as all of the gelatin and flavors will have dissolved into the liquid.

Comment: Veges are pig fodder or compost. If you use bones with meat on them, or whole chicken pieces, pull the meat out after 45-60 minutes. Let it cool a bit and remove the meat. Toss the bones and gristle back in to continue cooking. The meat retains it's flavor, and you get to extract all the collogen out of the bones. This is what I do when making a quick stock for Chicken Gumbo.

Comment: Flavorful? If there's any flavor left in the meat, then you haven't simmered it long enough.

Answer (score 7):

I recently made vegetable broth and used the leftovers as the base for a creamy potato soup:

I threw out onion skins and bay leaves, but kept the rest and added an equal weight of potatoes, water to cover, boiled and seasoned it, blended, and simmered with cream.

Simple, efficient.

Answer (score 4):

I would dump them, with the caveat that some chefs reserve bones for making a second, lighter stock. I've only heard of this being done with Veal, so your mileage may vary.

I've also heard of people combining stock and chicken salad making by throwing a whole chicken in to the stock pot, then using the white meat for salad.

This offends me on many levels, but I'll just say that it probably makes for bad chicken salad, and also almost certainly makes for cloudy stock.

Comment: Why on earth would that make for bad chicken salad?

Comment: I'm imagining saltless overcooked white breast meat as a start; In my head, seasoned roasted white meat would be a much better start. I admit that I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: I've tried it, and it's heavenly. Boil a whole chicken with onion, carrot, celery, herbs, salt and pepper for about 90 minutes. Remove the white meat for later use and continue cooking the bones for another 60-90 minutes. Tasty broth and tasty meat. Great if you're making pot pie.

Comment: Veal bones are sometimes used a second time, "Remouillage" or 're-wetting' of the bones.  This secondary simmering of the bones is usually done with just water for a few more hours.  This secondary cooking water is then used as the water for the next batch of actual veal stock.  The benefit is to extract the mamximum flavor from veal bones before discarding.  The drawback is that you then have to have room in your refrigerator, cooler, or freezer for the secondary stock until you make your next batch.

Comment: Remi is extremely useful in restaurant contexts, when you need liquid with some flavour but nothing that will assert itself in the final product. I am at a serious loss to imagine a useful frequent use for remi at home.

Comment: Keller mixes Remouillage and original stock and reduces them together (called 'Veal 1' and 'Veal 2' in his kitchen). I've done it before; it makes a very nice stock.

Comment: So Ceejayoz, I made a simple Poulet a Pot recipe last night, partly motivated by this conversation. Two reasons not to use a whole chicken if you want stock (not broth): first is that fat control is harder since you've got a whole bunch of chicken skin in there rendering. Second is that it is in fact cloudy, like I thought it would be. That said, we cut the chicken up, dipped in salt and had with mustard and veggies, and it tasted great.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Ah..... any stock I make simmers for at least 8 to 12 hours. I guess my stock is richer than yours, but your use of meat would not be possible with what I'd have left.

Answer (score 3):

I pureed all the left over vegetables, added garlic  powder, Adobe seasoning, salt, pepper and Italian seasoning. Oh, and a little powdered chicken bullion.  Put in bowl and topped with dollop of sour cream. Yummy!

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with all the comments about the lack of flavor and palatable texture in the boiled vegetables, they do have value. If you’re trying to increase insoluble fiber in your diet, anything that you can purée them and add them to (like a creamy potato soup or spaghetti sauce as suggested above) will have that benefit .  At most, the cellulose content of onions is reduced by about 15% from boiling.  I’m not sure if the longer boiling time reduces it significantly more.

Answer (score 3):

So when I make beef stock I use the pressure cooker technique 3 hours and then everything is mush. After everything is sieved I go through the mush carefully removing anything which could be bone and remaining sinew. I then add lots of fresh parsley basil tomato passata and a bulb of confit garlic a decent glug of decent olive oil, food processor for 1 minute and you have a passable if somewhat strangely textured bolognaise sauce.

Answer (score 2):

I actually Googled this myself because I was wondering about the same thing. Someone else also suggested pureeing the veggies and adding them to spaghetti sauce. http://vegetarian.betterrecipes.com/vegetable-puree-leftover-vegetables-after-making-vegetable-stock.html

Answer (score 0):

If there's any flavor left in chicken meat on the bone, or much collagen left in the bones after stock making, I'd say it hasn't simmered long enough.  The stock should be both flavorful and unctuous, which means the meat will be flavorless and the bones brittle.  Overnight is great for this, at a very low temperature - but with aromatics added later.

If you boil your stock, the tiny orifices in the bones from where collagen leaches will be sealed off, and the result will be much thinner than it could otherwise be.

Comment: Try pressure cooking for stock - way easier than overnight.

Answer (score -1):

Made stock last night with chicken carcass and assorted vegetable and fruit peelings. Used an InstantPot for 2 hours at high pressure. Separated and saved the clear stock.

Looked at the remaining solids, and reached for the hand blender. Added water and pureed the lot, including the bones. Gave it another 15 minutes at high pressure in the InstantPot.

A thick, smooth, opaque, dark brown, strongly smelling paste came out. Picture a concentrated sauce, or a liquidy pate. Judging from the aroma, probably too much orange peel this time around :)

Comment: As much as I know I need fiber and calcium and such, I'm not sure if blended chicken bones are quite what I'd want.  I also noticed that you didn't mention if you actually ate and/or tasted it, only that you smelled it.